# Wkhtmltopdf pagebreak in table with rowspan breaks the row-spanned

Tags: html, laravel, wkhtmltopdf

I am using Laravel 8, Snappy and wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 (with patched qt).
I generated a HTML table with the following structure:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1</td>
            <td>Col 2</td>
            <td>Col 3</td>
            <td>Col 4</td>
            <td>Col 5</td>
            <td>Col 6</td>
            <td>col 7</td>
            <td>col n</td>
            <td>col n+1</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="13">Title 1</td>
            <td rowspan="13">Sub-title 1</td>
            <td> x </td>
            <td></td>
            <td> 10.5-12 </td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    12.260
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    12.300
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> y</td>
            <td> mgE/l </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    0.080
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    0.080
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> z </td>
            <td> mmol/l </td>
            <td> 0.04 </td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    0.040
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    0.040
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> a </td>
            <td> mgE/l </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    20.800
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    23.300
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> b </td>
            <td> mgE/l </td>
            <td> 25 </td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    23.500
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    26.400
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> c </td>
            <td> mg/l </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    129.000
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    148.000
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> d </td>
            <td> mg/l </td>
            <td> &lt; 0.3 </td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    0.430
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    1.230
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> e </td>
            <td> μS/cm </td>
            <td> &lt; 8000 </td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    5320.000
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    5960.000
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> f </td>
            <td> bar </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> g </td>
            <td></td>
            <td> miss </td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    miss
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    miss
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> h </td>
            <td></td>
            <td> miss </td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    value
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    value
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> i </td>
            <td></td>
            <td> miss </td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    miss
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    miss
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> j </td>
            <td></td>
            <td> miss </td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    miss
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    miss
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="13">Title 2</td>
            <td rowspan="13">Sub-title 2 </td>
            <td> k </td>
            <td></td>
            <td> 10.5-12 </td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    11.420
                </a>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> l </td>
            <td> mgE/l </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    0.000
                </a>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>m</td>
            <td> mmol/l </td>
            <td> 0.04 </td>
            <td>
                <span>N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    &lt;0.010
                </a>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This table can grow in columns and in rows depending on the data. When put to PDF, the page break is placed between rows, but the first and second cell are divided between pages and their text is sometimes overlapped by the repeated thead. It looks like the rowspan is not taken into account when page-breaking the table.
I want to avoid page break between non rowspan cells.

Comment: Maybe 
`tr { break-inside:avoid; }` helps

Comment: Tried that, also tried `break-before:avoid;` all rows but the ones containing td with rowspan, but with without luck.

Comment: `tr, td, a, span { break-inside:avoid; }` ??

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but no, still breaks inside the first td of the row.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the number of cells per row... The first `tr` has 9 `td`'s and most other have 7.